# 'ValuesListQuerySet' object has no attribute 'group_by'

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, django-views, database-schema

I am trying to display sizes and colors of a store product according to a store:

```
store1: sizes=S,M,L colors=Red,blue

store2: sizes=L,Xl  colors=yellow,green
```

I tried to use `values_list` along with `group_by` but it throws the error

> 'ValuesListQuerySet' object has no attribute 'group_by'

It seems like `group_by` is not a part of django. What can I do to group my query as above?

**models.py**

A store contains a product which can be of different sizes and colors. Similarly a product can be available in more than one store.

```
class StoreProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product')
    category = models.ForeignKey('products.Category')
    store = models.ForeignKey('Store')
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True , blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True , blank=True)
    sizes = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True , blank=True)
    colors = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True , blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.title


class Store(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , null=True , blank=True)
    StoreName = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default = '')
    items = models.ManyToManyField('products.Product', through=StoreProduct)
    brand = models.ForeignKey('products.Brand' , null=True , blank=True)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default = '')
    Area = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default = '')
    Address = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    MallName = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True , blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True ,unique=True)
```

**views.py**

```
 StoreProduct.objects.filter(product=productobj) \
   .values_list('sizes', flat=True) \
   .group_by('store')
```

Comment: then how can i group sizes according store in the above scenario

Comment: There is 2 methods that can be used `aggregate` and `annotate`  but first think of your sql:

SELECT sizes
FROM StoreProduct
GROUP BY store

Do you think it's valid?

Comment: why it isnt valid?.then how can display sizes according to store?

Comment: A store contains a product which can be of different sizes and colors...and similarly a product can be available on more than one store...so cant we display which store has sizes and colors of a particular product?

Comment: is anything wrong with my db design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StoreProduct` represents a `Product` in a particular store, so to get "*display which store has which sizes and colors of a particular product*" you should query `Product` instead. Something like:

`p1=products.Product() #object representing your particular product
p1.storeproducts_set.all().value_list('store','sizes','colors')`

when evaluated thish should return a list of tuples containing "*which store has which sizes and color*" of product `p1`.

Comment: Glad, that I was able to help you. If it works you might want to mark it as an answer.